# Azure Application Insights - API to get satus of enable and disable for an application outside of Azure Portal

Tags: azure-application-insights

How to Check the status of Azure Application Insight is enable or not for a particular application using API?

Comment: you might be able to do that using azure's ARM apis, but only for a subset of "enabled" states.  you can use Application Insights in lots of ways (status monitor, server side sdks+code, client side sdks+code) and that ARM check would only get you the "status monitor" part.  What *specifically* are you trying to do that you want to query this?

Comment: Thanks For Answering me on this.